# Pid filter is working for uprobes but not uretprobes

Tags: kernel, ebpf, libbpf, uprobe

While testing uprobes, found that PID filter is working only for a uprobe and not uretprobes.
I have two applications running and attached uprobe against each application with PIDs pid1 and pid2.

Sample code snippet below

```
uprobe_opts.func_name = "Func1";
uprobe_opts.retprobe = false;
uprobe_link =
        bpf_program__attach_uprobe_opts(bpf_func_ent,
                                        pid1,
                                        lib_path,
                                        0, &uprobe_opts);

uprobe_opts.func_name = "Func1";
uprobe_opts.retprobe = false;
uprobe_link =
       bpf_program__attach_uprobe_opts(bpf_func_ent,
                                        pid2,
                                        lib_path,
                                        0, &uprobe_opts);
```

Similarly attached uretprobes for the same applications using the PID filter

```
 uprobe_opts.func_name = "Func1";
 uprobe_opts.retprobe = true;
 uprobe_link =
        bpf_program__attach_uprobe_opts(bpf_func_ret,
                                        pid1,
                                        lib_path,
                                        0, &uprobe_opts);
 uprobe_opts.func_name = "Func1";
 uprobe_opts.retprobe = true;
 uprobe_link =
        bpf_program__attach_uprobe_opts(bpf_func_ret,
                                        pid2,
                                        lib_path,
                                        0, &uprobe_opts);
```

lib_path is path to shared library. Now when the function "Func1" is invoked from application i see that uprobe entry function is invoked only once, But the retuprobe function is hit twice.

Linux kernel version is 5.14 and libbpf version is 1.1.

I did try deleting the uretprobe for the second application with pid2 and it works fine, Both uprobe and uretprobe are invoked only once. But when I keep adding uretprobes using different Pid, the number of invocations of uretprobe increases linearly.